# Write sheet data from workbook n number of times

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading data from excel workbook with multiple sheets.
I am able to read data from multiple sheets, but i am trying to print particular sheet data **"n"** number of times.
**For Example** : My workbook contains 10 sheets numbered from 1-10, and i want to print "sheet 1" data 3 times, "Sheet 2" data 3 times..

Similarly, i will be printing every sheet data **"n"** number of times.

**Variables:** 
name-contains sheet names,occurances-contains number of times sheet data to be printed.

```
String[] name = { "a", "b", "c" };
    int[] occurances = { 2, 3, 4 };
    int c1 = 0;
    int c2 = 0;
```

**Excel file Reading code** :

```
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {

            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            if (datatypeSheet.getSheetName().equals(name[c1])) {
                c1++;
                for (int d = 0; d < occurances[c2]; d++) {
                    c2++;
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                        Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                            Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                            if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                                System.out.print(currentCell
                                        .getStringCellValue() + "--");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried, but  am getting all sheet data printed for 1 time.
Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code. Best way to understand why your code is not working is debugging (either through IDE or through logging).

```
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {

        // if your sheets are not in 'a', 'b', 'c' order this code 
        // will not work. think why
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
        if (datatypeSheet.getSheetName().equals(name[c1])) {
            c1++;

            // you need this variable to be fixed for your loop
            int occurancesForSheet = occurances[c2++];
            for (int d = 0; d < occurancesForSheet; d++) {

                // you need a new iterator each time
                Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                        if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                            System.out.print(currentCell
                                    .getStringCellValue() + "--");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , that served my requirement ,but I am able to figure out the reason for this comment "if your sheets are not in 'a', 'b', 'c' order this code will not work. think why"?

Comment: One more question , Can i change the value of data read from excel sheet.
For example : if sheet contains 4 integer values, and i am printing this sheet 10 times, i want to increment integer value by each iteration.
How can i achieve this. ?

Comment: you could use a variable for that

Comment: How can i use variables for that, I mean i can have "n" number of sheets , with "n" number of integer values per sheet .

Comment: Well, in that case you could use an array with one value for each sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I tried doing that and i am able to write data but i want to write data with spaces , for ex: data should be written like this   "      21.21". It should be written with leading spaces.That is also writing well, but when i do double click on that cell data , the leading spaces are removed .

Comment: seems like trimming spaces is the behaviour of your spreadsheeting software, you could try it: open excel and try to enter " 21.21" to a cell. and btw, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers